# Reactjs tests (react testing library)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Can anyone help with how I can test the component below? I am using the testing-library / react library and am having difficulties.

```
export default function BodyCardConfirmacaoSeguranca({ email, celular }) {
    const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState(null);

    const handleSelectCard = (value) => {
        if (value === selectedCard) {
            setSelectedCard(null);
        } else {
            setSelectedCard(value);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <CardEnvioCod
                data-testid="email"
                tipoEnvio="email"
                data={email}
                handleSelectCard={() => handleSelectCard('email')}
                selectedCard={selectedCard}
            />

            <CardEnvioCod
                data-testid="sms"
                tipoEnvio="sms"
                data={telefone(celular)}
                handleSelectCard={() => handleSelectCard('sms')}
                selectedCard={selectedCard}
            />
        </>
    );
}
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
    it('', () => {
        const { findByTestId } = Render(
            <ThemeProvider theme={AppTheme}>
                <BodyCardConfirmacaoSeguranca />
            </ThemeProvider>,
        );

        const email = findByTestId('email');
        const sms = findByTestId('sms');

        fireEvent.change(email, { selectedCard: 'email' });
        fireEvent.change(sms, { selectedCard: 'sms' });
    });
```

I need to test the handleSelectCard function and its call on the components

below follows the  code, it has not yet been tested. It is used inside the , can I be doing the test in the wrong place too? I'm lost

```
export default function CardEnvioCod({
    tipoEnvio,
    data,
    handleSelectCard,
    selectedCard,
}) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const selected = selectedCard === tipoEnvio;

    const icon =
        tipoEnvio === TIPO_ENVIO.EMAIL ? (
            <EmailOutlined
                className={clsx(classes.icon, selected && classes.selected)}
            />
        ) : (
            <PhoneAndroidOutlinedIcon
                className={clsx(classes.icon, selected && classes.selected)}
            />
        );
    const text =
        tipoEnvio === TIPO_ENVIO.EMAIL
            ? 'Enviar por e-mail:'
            : 'Enviar por SMS:';

    useEffect(() => {}, []);

    return (
        <Grid container justify="center" className={classes.container}>
            <Grid
                item
                component={Paper}
                variant="outlined"
                lg={7}
                xs={12}
                square
                elevation={0}
                className={clsx(classes.root, selected && classes.selected)}
                onClick={handleSelectCard}
            >
                <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="center">
                    <Grid item lg={1} xs={2}>
                        <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={8}>
                        <Grid container justify="flex-start" direction="column">
                            <Typography
                                className={clsx(
                                    classes.titleCard,
                                    selected && classes.selected,
                                )}
                            >
                                {text}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography
                                title={data}
                                className={classes.divData}
                            >
                                {data}
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item lg={1} xs={2}>
                        <Grid container justify="flex-end">
                            {selected ? (
                                <CheckBoxIcon
                                    fontSize="large"
                                    cursor="pointer"
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <CheckBoxOutlineBlank
                                    color="primary"
                                    fontSize="large"
                                    cursor="pointer"
                                />
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Comment: What is `CardEnvioCod ` and how did you test it? Your test to assert `handleSelectCard` callback is invoked *should* be there. Also, `CardEnvioCod` doesn't have an exposed `onChange` prop. Can you update your question with `CardEnvioCod` component code (any any tests for it)?

Comment: Updated as requested!

Comment: I haven't done the test yet <CardEnvioCod/>

Comment: I think you are trying to update your CardEnvioCod props by firing a change event on an HTML element which is wrong. fireEvent.change purpose is to update an input element value (ie type something in a text field).